# Node - Uploaded jpg cannot be opened on server

Tags: node.js, jpeg, fs

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @robertklep and @vallo for pointing out that I was not parsing the multipart request properly.

Here's the updated server code with some re-worked sample code from [Busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy):

```
'use strict';

// Require
var http    = require('http');
var Busboy  = require('busboy');
var fs      = require('fs');

// Server
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: request.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`../db/images/${filename}`));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      response.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
      response.end("That's all folks!");
    });
    return request.pipe(busboy);
  }
  response.writeHead(404);
  response.end();
});
server.listen(8000, '192.168.7.25', () => {});
```

---

I am trying to post a jpg to an endpoint but the resulting image cannot be opened :

> The file “image_copy.jpg” could not be opened. It may be damaged or
>   use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

Some background:

- Everything (servers, storage) are being hosted locally
- Have made a decision to only use native Node modules like http and fs due to storage constraints on a microcontroller board
- Am using form-data as it eases the pain of multi-part forms and uploads as well as sets the correct request headers

Here is some sample code broken into two scripts:

**Server**

```
'use strict';

// Require
var http = require('http');

// Server
var server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    var body = [];
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body.push(chunk);
    });
    request.on('end', function() {
        saveImage(Buffer.concat(body),null);
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.end('thanks')
    });
});
server.listen(8000, '192.168.7.25', () => {});


// Process
function saveImage(data,callback) {
    var fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile('../db/images/image_copy.jpg', data, function(err) {});
}
```

**Client**

```
'use strict';

// Require
var FormData    = require('form-data');
var fs          = require('fs');
var http        = require('http');

// Vars
var form = new FormData();

// Process
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream('/temp/1.jpg'));
var request = http.request({
  hostname: '192.168.7.25',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/api/premises/v1/image',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: form.getHeaders()
});
form.pipe(request);
request.on('response', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

After executing, the jpg is uploaded and saved to the correct file location (and also has the same file size as the source jpg) but the new image can't be opened.

Even if I encode the incoming chunk as binary and set the encoding on fs.writeFile to binary, I get a similar result.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Are you confident both files are different? you can hash them to compare them, or use a program to check byte-to-byte differences

Comment: you can try sending something simpler, let's say a .txt file, and print on console right before you send it from the client and print the same when you receive it on the server. That way you can debug what's going on

Comment: @vallo I'm confident that the source jpg is a working jpg and not corrupted. I'm not trying to compare the images at this point. I just want the uploaded image to be properly encoded / not corrupted.

Comment: If you compare the images (or you test it with text files) you'll realize there extra info you're adding in the body and thus saving it as .jpg. Not sure how to fix it, but you got a clue now.

My original text file only had "asd" on it, and this is how the server-side txt file looks like: http://imgur.com/LmjB0j6

Comment: @vallo yes, i see where the file still has the disposition headers and boundaries. Now I need to research how to properly parse multipart/form-data from the buffer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client is uploading in `multipart/form-data` format, which is a format that can contain, amongst others, file data.

However, this means that the server should parse this format to extract the file data. Right now, the server is just taking the request body verbatim and writing it to a file.

The `multiparty` module can help you, and one of its usage examples shows you how to hook it up with `http.Server`: https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty#usage

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // parse a file upload
  var form = new multiparty.Form();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
  });

}).listen(8000);
```

Using that, you can extract the file data from (I think) `files.my_file` and write it to the file.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that extra step of properly parsing a multipart request. Adding an update up top. Thanks!